# What is the difference between Document and document in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am currently building an API for JavaScript, predominantly using Visual Studio 2010 and JetBrains WebStorm (brilliant if you're looking for a bulletproof JavaScript IDE).

Whilst looking through the intellisense list in Visual Studio (trying to familiarize myself with the JavaScript API), I noticed that both `Document` and `document` exist.

1. What is the difference between `Document` and `document`?
2. What is `document` an instance of (if any) ?
3. How does one use `Document` (as it is not a function, therefore, not constructable)?
4. Most importantly, What is the harm in "monkey-patching" `Document` to make it constructable?

The rationale behind these questions is that I want to create some objects that fit into my API (for example; `Document`, `HTMLElement` etc.), but as these appear to already exist in some respect, I'm not confident that I should be overwriting their native implementation.

Comment: MDN has created more confusion between "Document" vs "document" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: But W3School has used `document` all the places. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is the difference between `Document` and `document`?

`document` (or [`window.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.document)) is a reference to the document contained in the window. ([spec](http://www.whatwg.org/html#the-window-object))

`Document` is the DOM interface for documents, which is exposed on the global object. ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-document), [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-interfaces))

> How does one use `Document` (as it is not a function, therefore, not constructable)?

It's a host object and does not need to follow the EcmaScript spec - yet that does not mean it's not a function. It may differ from browser to browser as well. Yet it is not intended to be called (if you try it you'll get a `NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR`), there are other methods to instantiate/obtain new documents. What you can still use it for is

```
> document instanceof Document
true
> Document.prototype
DocumentPrototype {
    adoptNode: Function
    constructor: Document
    createAttribute: Function
    …
    querySelector: Function
    querySelectorAll: Function
}
|- NodePrototype
|- Object
```

so you could extend its prototype and use those methods on all `XMLDocuments`/`HTMLDocuments` in your app (but only if you know [what’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)).

> Most importantly, what is the harm in "monkey-patching" `Document` to make it constructable?

I'm not sure how you would do that. Overwriting it could harm every script that expects it to work as above (unless you fix the `prototype` property of your new function). And maybe the `Document` property of `window` is non-writable in some environments, so you could harm yourself.

Comment: So basically `Document.prototype` is *essentially* similar to `window.document`/`document`?

Comment: @Jaketr00: Similar? Sure. In fact, `Document.prototype.isPrototypeOf(window.document)` is `true` :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `Document` is the prototype definition for the `document` object of the global scope witch means that the `Document`'s prototype is share with his instance (`document`). like `Window` is the prototype definition for the `window` object.
2. The `Document` is native prototype object and you can't create instances of it, only one instance is created when the page is created (again, like the window) just like a single tone object.
3. I don't think that to override the `Document` will be a good practice.

My suggestion is to use a namespace for your API and create your Document and HTMLElement etc inside your api namespace, for example:

```
var api = {
    Document: { /* your implementation */ },
    HTMLElement: { /* your implementation */ }
    //...
};

var myDocument = new api.Document();
```

More then that, you can inherit the real `Document` prototype and use it in your own object like so:

```
api.Document = function(){ /* your implementation */ }
api.Document.prototype = Document.prototype;

var myDocument = new api.Document();
```

Hope this is help and I understood you question...