# trying to understand the difference between window and document objects in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the difference between window and document objects in js. I checked online, but I still don't have a clear understanding. From what I know: window is like a super document, it includes the document object. So if I use firefox to open one page: localhost/test.js, can I say the browser:firefox is window object, and the file test.js is the document object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A very detailed explanation: [Read here](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/)

Basically window is your browser's window and document is the HTML page inside it.
[image]

Comment: Does each document in the tabs of a browser share the same browser's window? That sounds very insecure if one page can see another pages globals. Many tell it is open but not how it is open. I hope I have not exposed the security hole by my question.

Answer (score 32):

The [**`window` object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) represents the current browsing context. It holds things like `window.location`, `window.history`, `window.screen`, `window.status`, or the `window.document`. Also, it has information about the framing setup (the `frames`, `parent`, `top`, `self` properties), and holds important interfaces such as `applicationCache`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `setTimeout`, `escape`, `console` or `localStorage`. Last but not least it acts as the global scope for JavaScript, i.e. all global variables are properties of it.

In contrast, the (`window.`)[**`document` object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) represents the DOM that is currently loaded in the `window` - it's just a part of it. A document holds information like the `documentElement` (usually `<html>`), the `forms` collection, the `cookie` string, its `location`, or its `readyState`. It also implements a different interface (there might be multiple [`Document`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16790174), for example an XML document obtained via ajax), with methods like `getElementById` or `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript that runs in the browser has Window as it's top level. This means that global variables will become properties of window:

```
// this code is not inside a function
var global1=22;
function test(){
  var local=88;
  window.global2=99;
  console.log(local);//logs 88 because
    // local is available within the body
    // of this function
  console.log(global1);//logs 22
}
console.log(typeof local);//logs undefined becaue were
  // outside the funciton body
test();
console.log(global2);//logs 99 because we added
   // global2 as a property of window
```

So window will contain all your global objects, this means that:
parseInt does the same as window.parseInt.

Window even contains itself so:

```
window===window.window.window;//is true
```

window does not have a getElementById, children, childNodes ... funciton because window is not an Html element and document is.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript applications have context, a scope where values are defined. The 'root' or  'global' object in the case of a browser is `window`.

The `window` object has a property (a variable) called `document` which stores a representation of the document. The document holds a model representation of the currently loaded document (such as `title`, `anchors`, etc). The `window` object represents the browser window where your document is displayed.

Also, if you in a script that is not in a function you define something like:

> ```
> var x = 10;
> ```

Really what you have done is define a variable in the global object. In the browser case this will be in `window`.

So `window.x` will have the value of 10.