# What's the differences between document and window

Tags: jquery, window, document

When we want to inspect the event of scroll to bottom in browser in jquery. So we may write:

`if $(window).scrollTop > $(document).height - $(window).height - 50
     doScrollEvent();  //Event we do to load data when scroll to the bottom`

So what's the difference  between document and window here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on Google, or here on StackOverflow, would have found a stack of answers. These will help you understand the difference.

1. [What is the difference between window, screen, and document in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript)
2. [trying to understand the difference between window and document objects in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227008/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-window-and-document-objects-in-js)

Comment: This should be a comment to close the question as a duplicate, not an answer.

Comment: @j08691. Good point thanks. Will mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`document` refers to the width of the page itself. `window` refers to the viewport (i.e. how big your browser window is).

Answer (score 0):

The window object represents an open window in a browser.
where as when an HTML document is loaded into a web browser, it becomes a document object. So there height and width may be different. 
One is a browser object and another is HTML dom object.

For more info look:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp