# Download text file from dynamically-created window

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a small bookmarklet which will allow teachers to highlight text on a webpage and download that selection as a plain text (.txt) file. I have [a demo page](http://dev.ohheybrian.com/getText/index.html) set up to show what I have working and where I'm stuck.

On the demo page, I can highlight text and download it directly using the "Download Selection" button. But, if you mis-highlight, you have to go back and do it again. The "Make Page" button grabs the highlighted text and creates a popup with the text for proofing.

**script.js**

```
function makePage(text) {
  var text = "";
  if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();

    var newPage = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=300,status=yes,menubar=no");
    newPage.document.write("<body><a id='download' download='text.txt'></a><p id='copy'>" + text + "</p><button id='download' onclick='getPlainText()'>Download</button><scipt type='text/javascript' src='script.js' defer></script></body></html>");
    console.log(text)
  }
}

function getPlainText(copy) {
  var text = "";
  if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    text = window.getElementById('copy').innerContent;

    var download = document.getElementById('download');
    download.href = 'data:text/plain;charset:utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    download.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  return text;
}
```

When I click the Download button on the popup, I get a TypeError in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: window.getElementById is not a function`

I've moved the script in the document, but regardless of where it is, the error returns and I can't figure out why. Any ideas on how to get that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right syntax is

```
document.getElementById()
```

try

```
function getPlainText(copy) {
  var text = "";
  if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    text = document.getElementById('copy').innerContent;

    var download = document.getElementById('download');
    download.href = 'data:text/plain;charset:utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    download.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

window object don't have getElementById method. Use document.getElementById instead

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call a function from and object that doesn't provide that function.

Instead of calling `window.getElemenyById()` you should be doing `document.GetElementById()`.

So to further clarify, here is your code with the proper correction.

```
function getPlainText(copy) {
  var text = "";
  if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    //Here from window to document
    text = document.getElementById('copy').innerContent;

    // Ironically you used "document" here ;]
    var download = document.getElementById('download');
    download.href = 'data:text/plain;charset:utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    download.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  return text;
}
```

A detailed difference between the two, as provided by an answer from the user [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227008/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-window-and-document-objects-in-js).

> The window object represents the current browsing context. It holds
>   things like window.location, window.history, window.screen,
>   window.status, or the window.document. Also, it has information about
>   the framing setup (the frames, parent, top, self properties), and
>   holds important interfaces such as applicationCache, XMLHttpRequest,
>   setTimeout, escape, console or localStorage. Last but not least it
>   acts as the global scope for JavaScript, i.e. all global variables are
>   properties of it.
>
> In contrast, the (window.)document object represents the DOM that is
>   currently loaded in the window - it's just a part of it. A document
>   holds information like the documentElement (usually ), the forms
>   collection, the cookie string, its location, or its readyState. It
>   also implements a different interface (there might be multiple
>   Documents, for example an XML document obtained via ajax), with
>   methods like getElementById or addEventListener.

[image]