# Does DOM API use constructors and prototypes in creating/manipulating nodes?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, constructor

I'm trying to understand DOM API through OOP frame of mind.  Since DOM API uses properties and methods that are built into the browser and `document` in, say, `document.createElement` is an instance of `Document`, is it safe to say that `document` is an instance created from the `Document` constructor?  For example, when I'm using DOM, is this what is happening in under the hood?:

```
let document = new Document();
```

where Document() is defined as something like:

```
class Document {
 constructor()
 //some properties and methods
}
```

Also, when the following codes are executed:

```
let link = document.querySelector('a');
link.textContent('This is a link');
```

is this a case where `link` inherits prototype from `Document` and the method `textContent` is invoked through a setter:

```
class Document {
 set textContent(x){
  some_variable = x;
 }
}
```

Is there a way to see the source code of `Document` other than `console.log(Document)`?

Comment: No, the `Document` function is builtin and implemented natively, not with JS code.

Comment: Can you expound on that? I'm not sure I know what that means

Comment: We don't know (and don't care) how `window.document` was instantiated, it already exists in the environment when our js code runs. I'm pretty sure it's not created through a js interface.

Comment: What is the relationship between the function Document and windows.document? The function Document seems to contain the prototype property like a regular constructor function

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790591/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document Object Model (DOM) is a programming API for HTML and XML documents. It defines the logical structure of documents and the way a document is accessed and manipulated.

Its not part of JS its a W3C standard implemented, The Document Object Model can be used with any programming language.

The actions performed using language bindings, it provides language bindings for Java and ECMAScript.

User can refer specification standard document at [Source W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html)